# How to programmatically know a required select list has no value on node add/edit form page?

Tags: forms

For a required field using select list widget, if there is no options, the field will show only one "-Select one-"  value on the node add/edit form page. So, how to know that by coding?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the field type. For a list field with text/numeric values, the output of the field API function [`field_info_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7.x) contains allowed values within its `settings` element. This field data can be fed into [`list_allowed_values()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!list!list.module/function/list_allowed_values/7.x) to retrieve either the static or dynamic list of allowed values for the field.

For example:

```
$field = field_info_field('field_myfield');
$values = list_allowed_values($field);
if (count($values) > 0) {
  // There are allow values
}
else {
  // There are no allowed values
}
```

Comment: It use your code snippet in a hook_form_alter to unset the submit button if there is no valid options in a required select list. This select list form element is an entity reference field populated by a entity reference views output. Unfortunately, even there is valid options in the select list, the submit button is still unset, and the page shows errors as below:

Comment: : Notice: Undefined index: allowed_values_function in list_allowed_values() (line 239 of /home/wzzhang/www/reg/modules/field/modules/list/list.module).
Notice: Undefined index: allowed_values in list_allowed_values() (line 248 of /home/wzzhang/www/reg/modules/field/modules/list/list.module).

Comment: Then I change my custom module's execution weight to 999 with SQL:  UPDATE system SET weight=999 WHERE name = 'mycustommodule'; The error still exists.

Comment: This was tested with a text/numeric list, you should update the question so that it mentions it's an entity ref field.