# How to hide the submit button on a node add/edit form page within which a entity reference select list has no valid option?

Tags: entities, forms

*Registration* content type has a required entity reference field. The widget of this field is a select list, the options are populated with a views entity reference display output. I want to hide(unset) the submit button if the views entity reference display returns no value.
I've asked [a question here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217406/how-to-programmatically-know-a-required-select-list-has-no-value-on-node-add-edi/217451?noredirect=1#comment266411_217451) for reference, I'm suggested to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using hook form FORM ID alter .

Once hooked in you find the $form item for the drop down list.  It'll be somewhere like

$form['field_my_entity_ref']['und']['#options']

So you should be able to make a check on the values in that array and if there are none then make the Submit button disabled .  My guess is

```
if ( count($form['field_my_entity_ref']['und']['#options']) < 1 ) {

   $form['#submit']['#disabled'] == TRUE;
 }
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/#disabled

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x